# Make flutterfire_ui show some screens in ltr direction rather than locale rtl direction?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, localization, firebaseui

I am using a [flutterfire_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui) package to manage the sign in process with phone authentication. When a user signs with phone he/she will be required to enter: a country code, a phone number and an OTP. The screens will use the default direction based on the app locale.

I am declaring the app locale as Arabic. Now although Arabic is an rtl language, still the country code, the phone numbers and the OTP will need to be displayed and entered in an ltr direction since they are all numbers. The screens that flutterfire_ui provides displays those in rtl direction.

What do you suggest *as a minimalist approach* to override this behaviour and specify a direction for those screens?

1. Screen snapshots to show current behaviour:

   1. [Screen for entering phone number with 'ar' as locale. Default direction set to rtl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyPBg.png)
   2. [Screen for entering OTP with 'ar' as locale. Default direction set to rtl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKQXl.png)
2. Screen snapshots to show desired behaviour:

   1. [Screen for entering phone number with 'en' as locale. Default direction set to ltr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJBIc.png)
   2. [Screen for entering OTP with 'en' as locale. Default direction set to ltr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ppyb.png)

Here is minimum code to reproduce the issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/i10n.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'myapp',
      locale: const Locale('ar', 'SA'),
      supportedLocales: [const Locale('ar', 'SA')],
      localizationsDelegates: [
        FlutterFireUILocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SignInScreen(
        providerConfigs: [
          PhoneProviderConfiguration(),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the UI library. Did you consider filing it as an issue on the [GitHub repo of the plugin](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22plugin%3A+ui%22)? The maintainers are pretty active.

Comment: thx @FrankvanPuffelen This is filed as an issue in the repo. 
[link](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9379)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't totally solve the issue but it is an acceptable-*ish* workaround.

I converted the locale back to 'en' and supplied the localizationsDelegates with overwritten labels in Arabic. This will make the sign-in screens look more acceptable.

If you are applying this workaround just take an extra care as this change may impact the rest of your app. in my case it didn't have an overall impact on the rest of the app as each widget has its styles hardcoded.

Here are the changes needed to be applied on the code:

1. Change locale to 'en'

```dart
locale: const Locale('en', 'SA'),
supportedLocales: [const Locale('en', 'SA')],
```

2. Modify localizationDelegates as follows

```dart
localizationsDelegates: [
   FlutterFireUILocalizations.withDefaultOverrides(const LabelOverrides()),
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
   FlutterFireUILocalizations.delegate,
],
```

3. Added LabelOverrides

```dart
class LabelOverrides extends DefaultLocalizations {
  @override
  final String emailInputLabel;
  @override
  final String passwordInputLabel;
  @override
  final String signInActionText;
  @override
  final String registerActionText;
  @override
  final String linkEmailButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInButtonText;
  @override
  final String registerButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInWithPhoneButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInWithGoogleButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInWithAppleButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInWithFacebookButtonText;
  @override
  final String signInWithTwitterButtonText;
  @override
  final String phoneVerificationViewTitleText;
  @override
  final String verifyPhoneNumberButtonText;
  @override
  final String verifyCodeButtonText;
  @override
  final String verifyingPhoneNumberViewTitle;
  @override
  final String unknownError;
  @override
  final String smsAutoresolutionFailedError;
  @override
  final String smsCodeSentText;
  @override
  final String sendingSMSCodeText;
  @override
  final String verifyingSMSCodeText;
  @override
  final String enterSMSCodeText;
  @override
  final String emailIsRequiredErrorText;
  @override
  final String isNotAValidEmailErrorText;
  @override
  final String userNotFoundErrorText;
  @override
  final String emailTakenErrorText;
  @override
  final String accessDisabledErrorText;
  @override
  final String wrongOrNoPasswordErrorText;
  @override
  final String signInText;
  @override
  final String registerText;
  @override
  final String registerHintText;
  @override
  final String signInHintText;
  @override
  final String signOutButtonText;
  @override
  final String phoneInputLabel;
  @override
  final String phoneNumberIsRequiredErrorText;
  @override
  final String phoneNumberInvalidErrorText;
  @override
  final String profile;
  @override
  final String name;
  @override
  final String deleteAccount;
  @override
  final String passwordIsRequiredErrorText;
  @override
  final String confirmPasswordIsRequiredErrorText;
  @override
  final String confirmPasswordDoesNotMatchErrorText;
  @override
  final String confirmPasswordInputLabel;
  @override
  final String forgotPasswordButtonLabel;
  @override
  final String forgotPasswordViewTitle;
  @override
  final String resetPasswordButtonLabel;
  @override
  final String verifyItsYouText;
  @override
  final String differentMethodsSignInTitleText;
  @override
  final String findProviderForEmailTitleText;
  @override
  final String continueText;
  @override
  final String countryCode;
  @override
  final String codeRequiredErrorText;
  @override
  final String invalidCountryCode;
  @override
  final String chooseACountry;
  @override
  final String enableMoreSignInMethods;
  @override
  final String signInMethods;
  @override
  final String provideEmail;
  @override
  final String goBackButtonLabel;
  @override
  final String passwordResetEmailSentText;
  @override
  final String forgotPasswordHintText;
  @override
  final String emailLinkSignInButtonLabel;
  @override
  final String signInWithEmailLinkViewTitleText;
  @override
  final String signInWithEmailLinkSentText;
  @override
  final String sendLinkButtonLabel;
  @override
  final String arrayLabel;
  @override
  final String booleanLabel;
  @override
  final String mapLabel;
  @override
  final String nullLabel;
  @override
  final String numberLabel;
  @override
  final String stringLabel;
  @override
  final String typeLabel;
  @override
  final String valueLabel;
  @override
  final String cancelLabel;
  @override
  final String updateLabel;
  @override
  final String northInitialLabel;
  @override
  final String southInitialLabel;
  @override
  final String westInitialLabel;
  @override
  final String eastInitialLabel;
  @override
  final String timestampLabel;
  @override
  final String latitudeLabel;
  @override
  final String longitudeLabel;
  @override
  final String geopointLabel;
  @override
  final String referenceLabel;

  const LabelOverrides({
    this.emailInputLabel = 'البريد الإلكتروني',
    this.passwordInputLabel = 'كلمة المرور',
    this.signInActionText = 'تسجيل الدخول',
    this.registerActionText = 'تسجيل جديد',
    this.signInButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول',
    this.registerButtonText = 'تسجيل جديد',
    this.linkEmailButtonText = 'التالي',
    this.signInWithPhoneButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول برقم الهاتف',
    this.signInWithGoogleButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول باستخدام Google',
    this.signInWithAppleButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول باستخدام Apple',
    this.signInWithTwitterButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول باستخدام Twitter',
    this.signInWithFacebookButtonText = 'تسجيل الدخول باستخدام Facebook',
    this.phoneVerificationViewTitleText = 'أدخل رقم هاتفك',
    this.verifyPhoneNumberButtonText = 'التالي',
    this.verifyCodeButtonText = 'تحقق',
    this.verifyingPhoneNumberViewTitle = 'أدخل رمز التحقق المرسل برسالة نصية',
    this.unknownError = 'حدث خطأ غير متوقع',
    this.smsAutoresolutionFailedError = 'حدث خطأ أثناء محاولة قراءة الرمز تلقائياً. رجاءً قم بإدخاله يدوياً',
    this.smsCodeSentText = 'تم إرسال رمز التحقق برسالة نصية',
    this.sendingSMSCodeText = 'جاري إرسال الرمز برسالة نصية...',
    this.verifyingSMSCodeText = 'جاري التحقق من الرمز المرسل...',
    this.enterSMSCodeText = 'أدخل الرمز المرسل',
    this.emailIsRequiredErrorText = 'البريد الإلكتروني مطلوب',
    this.isNotAValidEmailErrorText = 'رجاء قم بإدخال بريد إلكتروني صالح',
    this.userNotFoundErrorText = 'هذا الحساب غير موجود',
    this.emailTakenErrorText = 'هذا البريد الإلكتروني مستخدم مسبقاً',
    this.accessDisabledErrorText = 'تم تعطيل الوصول إلى هذا الحساب مؤقتًا',
    this.wrongOrNoPasswordErrorText = 'كلمة المرور غير صالحة أو أن هذا المستخدم ليس لديه كلمة مرور',
    this.signInText = 'تسجيل الدخول',
    this.registerText = 'إنشاء حساب',
    this.registerHintText = 'ليس لديك حساب مسبقا؟',
    this.signInHintText = 'لديك حساب مسبقا؟',
    this.signOutButtonText = 'تسجيل الخروج',
    this.phoneInputLabel = 'رقم الهاتف',
    this.phoneNumberInvalidErrorText = 'رقم الهاتف المدخل غير صالح',
    this.phoneNumberIsRequiredErrorText = 'رقم الهاتف مطلوب',
    this.profile = 'الملف الشخصي',
    this.name = 'الاسم',
    this.deleteAccount = 'حذف الحساب',
    this.passwordIsRequiredErrorText = 'كلمة المرور مطلوبة',
    this.confirmPasswordIsRequiredErrorText = 'قم بتأكيد كلمة مرورك',
    this.confirmPasswordDoesNotMatchErrorText = 'كلمات المرور المدخلة غير متطابقة',
    this.confirmPasswordInputLabel = 'تأكيد كلمة المرور',
    this.forgotPasswordButtonLabel = 'نسيت كلمة المرور؟',
    this.forgotPasswordViewTitle = 'استرجاع كلمة المرور المنسية',
    this.resetPasswordButtonLabel = 'إعادة تعيين كلمة المرور',
    this.verifyItsYouText = 'تحقق من هويتك',
    this.differentMethodsSignInTitleText = 'استخدم إحدى الطرق التالية لتسجيل الدخول',
    this.findProviderForEmailTitleText = 'أدخل بريدك الإلكتروني للمتابعة',
    this.continueText = 'استمرار',
    this.countryCode = 'رمز الدولة',
    this.codeRequiredErrorText = 'رمز الدولة مطلوب',
    this.invalidCountryCode = 'رمز الدولة هذا غير صالح',
    this.chooseACountry = 'اختر الدولة',
    this.enableMoreSignInMethods = 'تفعيل المزيد من طرق تسجيل الدخول',
    this.signInMethods = 'طرق تسجيل الدخول',
    this.provideEmail = 'أدخل بريدك الإلكتروني وكلمة المرور',
    this.goBackButtonLabel = 'رجوع',
    this.passwordResetEmailSentText = 'لقد أرسلنا إليك بريدًا إلكترونيًا يحتوي على رابط لإعادة تعيين كلمة المرور الخاصة بك. من فضلك تفقد بريدك الالكتروني',
    this.forgotPasswordHintText = 'أدخل بريدك الإلكتروني وسنرسل لك رابطًا لإعادة تعيين كلمة مرورك',
    this.emailLinkSignInButtonLabel = 'تسجيل الدخول عن طريق الرابط',
    this.signInWithEmailLinkViewTitleText = 'تسجيل الدخول عن طريق الرابط',
    this.signInWithEmailLinkSentText = 'لقد أرسلنا رابط تسجيل الدخول إلى بريدك الإلكتروني. تفقد صندوق رسائلك واضغط على الرابط لتسجيل الدخول',
    this.sendLinkButtonLabel = 'أرسل رابط تسجيل الدخول',
    this.arrayLabel = 'مصفوفة',
    this.booleanLabel = 'قيمة منطقية',
    this.mapLabel = 'كائن',
    this.nullLabel = 'بدون قيمة',
    this.numberLabel = 'رقم',
    this.stringLabel = 'نص',
    this.typeLabel = 'نوع',
    this.valueLabel = 'قيمة',
    this.cancelLabel = 'إلغاء',
    this.updateLabel = 'تحديث',
    this.northInitialLabel = 'شمال',
    this.southInitialLabel = 'جنوب',
    this.westInitialLabel = 'غرب',
    this.eastInitialLabel = 'شرق',
    this.timestampLabel = 'طابع زمني',
    this.longitudeLabel = 'خط الطول',
    this.latitudeLabel = 'خط العرض',
    this.geopointLabel = 'نقطة جغرافية',
    this.referenceLabel = 'مرجع',
  });
}
```

Comment: This solution combined with this [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S05fvqzzgzE) will be even a better workaround. The idea is to use ltr locale in the first runapp and then rtl locale in the second call to runapp. use it with caution though. To put it in other words, you use the first pass of runapp with 'en' locale to sign in the users. Once they are signed in you use the runapp again with 'ar' locale.